# Animate opening a new window with NSWindowController

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, animation

Starting with Mac OS X 10.7, new `NSDocument` windows as well as alert windows open with an animation. Windows opened with `NSWindowController`'s `showWindow:` method, however, get no animation.

Is there a way for these windows to get the same animation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can define how a window opens.

In the Interface Inspector under Animation you can choose Document Window Style, and you should get the same behaviour.

Or in code:

```
[self.window setAnimationBehavior:NSWindowAnimationBehaviorDocumentWindow];
```

---

Here all the behaviours you can use

```
enum {
    NSWindowAnimationBehaviorDefault = 0,       // let AppKit infer animation behavior for this window
    NSWindowAnimationBehaviorNone = 2,          // suppress inferred animations (don't animate)

    NSWindowAnimationBehaviorDocumentWindow = 3,
    NSWindowAnimationBehaviorUtilityWindow = 4,
    NSWindowAnimationBehaviorAlertPanel = 5
};
```